# Connect ECT to SharePoint List in InfoPath?

Tags: 2010, list, infopath, bcs, external-content-type

I'm trying to create a list in Infopath 2010. I'd like one of the fields to be a drop down list that connects to an external content type list. It doesn't show any of the External Content Type Lists when I select a list to pick from. Is it possible to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the below link. It explains very concisely how to do that

http://techdhaan.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/consuming-external-content-typesbcs-in-infopath-forms/

Working with **External Content Types and Infopath**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554886.aspx

http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/infopath-2010-designing-external-list-forms/

http://lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2010/11/07/modifying-external-list-forms-with-infopath-2010.aspx (now dead)

Comment: I just found this article on my own! Thank you for linkingi t though. But I'm running into some trouble: http://i.imgur.com/FpMl6.png as you can see.. External Item Picker isn't available.

Comment: I've now accomplished all that was done in the tutorial, but nothing will show up when i query the search box. I'm unsure of whether I have the correct "System Instance Name" or not.